# atomic thread fence and consume operation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-fences

I do (I think) understand what a consume operation is when it deals with atomic operation.

However, since there is no data directly linked to a fence, I wonder if there is case where it is useful to use `std::memory_order_consume` with an `std::atomic_thread_fence` ?

Comment: The C++ standard does not recommend it: _Prefer memory_order::acquire, which provides stronger guarantees than memory_order::consume. 
Implementations have found it infeasible to provide performance better than that of memory_order::acquire. Specification revisions are under consideration_..

Comment: Do you have a source or something like that? And it is not exactly what I ask for. I know that acquire is stronger than consume, but I wanted to know if there was one usefulness with `atomic_thread_fence`. However, thank you to advice me that the standard will maybe change :) .

Comment: It does not answer your question, it's just a comment if someone considers using 'consume' operations or fences.
Since it's the C++ standard giving this advice, I thought it'd be worth mentioning. The quote (cursive) is from draft version n4750, par. 32.4.1-3

Comment: And you did well.That's why I thanked you :). I just wanted to know if there was one utility or not, even if it is, now, deprecated :).

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounded blunt - not intentional..

Comment: In theory or in practice? If your compiler isn't interested in making consume work as designed, he will fall back on acquire which might be significantly less efficient on some CPU for frequently read data. And you will have made the significant effort to write possibly very silly consuming code for nothing, and that code might be unoptimized and less efficient than simple natural acquire code. You might want to check the compiler manual before doing that effort.

Comment: @LWimsey "_Implementations have found it infeasible to provide performance better than that of memory_order::acquire_" a very silly claim; people have been writing consuming code in as high level language as C++ (language GNU C) for years. Anyway, sufficient use of volatile provides **exactly** the desired consuming behavior (in reasonable cases).

Comment: "memory order acquire may be used as
a substitute for memory order consume, however doing
so results in **costly** explicit memory-fence **instructions**
(or, where available, load-acquire instructions)
**on** weakly ordered systems such as **ARM, Itanium,
and PowerPC**" [p0098r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0098r0.pdf) An optimized example of a consumer: [What is RCU, Fundamentally?](https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/)

Comment: @curiousguy was asking in theory more than in practice :).

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Making consume just a choice of atomic operation (like sequenced, release, acquire) was an error, consume should be a qualifier like const and volatile. It should apply to any variable and function. (I don't know if that's the committee's answer, but it's the right answer.)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier The proposed fix for consume is to make the result of a consume load a distinct type, via a class template *not* a core language qualifier like `volatile`, to avoid changing the C++ type rules I guess. But it's in line with what I previously wrote.